# Firebase Cloud Firestore request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a MESSAGERECAP collection which includes a unique id for each message, the id of the receiver of the message, the id of the sender and the message itself. In my application, when the user clicks on a friend to chat with him, I want the chat activity to start with the list of messages they have both sent.
I did this but obviously it does not give the desired result :

```
Query query = messageRef.orderBy("mssgId",Query.Direction.DESCENDING); 
// with messageRef a reference to the MESSAGERECAP collection
```

Here is an overview of my database

[image]

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?

Comment: What exactly is obviously not the right result?

Comment: Doug Stevenson the request that I wrote recovers all the messages of the MESAGERECAP collection. While I want to recover all messages between 2 users. A bit like whatsapp, when you click on a friend X, you only see the messages that this friend x and you had exchanged.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the whole list because you are not filtering the data, just ordering it. If you check the [Querying documentation for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), also provided by @FrankVanPuffelen on the comments of your question, you can see that you have to use `.where()` to filter the data that you want to retrieve.

Also, as pointed out by @Jay in the comments, you can use [Compound Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) to create a logical AND on your query to retrieve the data you want.

So if you do something like:

```
messageRef.where("senderId", "==", [currentUserId])
          .where("receiver_id", "==", [receiverUserId])
          .orderBy("mssgId",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

When you execute this query you will get all the messages sent by the current user to the receiving user of the correponding id.

Comment: I get what you're saying in general but *You cannot perform complex queries in firestore* is not accurate. The OP wants turn return all documents where sender == x and receiver == y (a logical AND), and you can certainly do that in Firestore. See [Compound Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

Comment: @Jay you are correct, my mistake, I will edit that into the answer, thanks for pointing that out.